# How high and when the bead will be on a spinning parabolically bent wire?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Imagine a wire, bend it parabolically with equation $ 4ay = x^2 $, and the vertex as usually at the origin. It is now rotated with angular velocity, $\omega$, on an axis, passing in its plane through the vertex. A bead, of mass $m$, inserted in the wire, just slightly displaced from the vertex. Then calculate the max height it attains and at what time, would it?

> This isn't a homework question just came out of curiosity!

*What I did*-
[image: my try]

Normal $N$ is perpendicularly up from the bead, and the weight, $mg$ is vertically downwards, and the centerifugal force, $F_c$ is horizontally right, $$ F_c = \frac {mv^2}{R} = m \omega ^2 R = m \omega ^2 x $$
where x is the x coord of the coordinate plane.
If $\theta$ is from horizontal then, $$N cos \theta = m \omega ^2 x $$ $$ N sin \theta = mg $$ $$ tan \theta = \frac {g}{\omega ^2 x}$$ After differentiating the curve, $$ \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {x}{2a} = m = tan (90 -\theta) $$
And $$ tan (90 -\theta) = \frac{\omega ^2 x}{g} = \frac {x}{2a}$$But the prob is the x gets cancelled and I get a wrong relation between $g$ and $\omega$. Am I missing something? Is there any alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations are correct and it can only mean that at certain $\omega^2=g/2a$ the body can be stabilized for any x on the wire and for any $\omega^2\neq g/2a$ the solution will not be stable and probably bead will fall to the center for $\omega^2<g/2a$ and will fly away for the $\omega^2>g/2a$

Comment: Ooh, is there any way of finding height? And time?